# In vuejs3, what is the best to share async data with components?

Tags: vuejs3

I have a vuejs3 plugin to get data from an api with async axios calls.
Data from api are stored in vuex store.

The components watch the data from vuex store and update the display when data change.

My question:
Is there a better solution to do that ? Without vuex ?

Thanks

Comment: For me it is not clear, what you are asking. It also depends on the application you are building and if multiple component share the same data.

Comment: I have a component that call a plugin method. This plugin method call (async) axios to get data from an api. How the component can get the data collected in the plugin (without vuex) ? I hope my explanation are clearer

Comment: from what I can read, call api from vuex action is a good solution. So I will move to this solution.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand the question, you can simply have a `ref` or a `reactive` object, if using composition API (simplified by using axios directly):

```
<script setup>
import { ref } from 'vue';
import axios from 'axios';

const asyncData = ref();
axios.get('/path').then((response) => asyncData.value = response.data);
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks Thomas, I've tried that but I guess I missed something, because the asyncData variable is undefined in the component which use the plugin where asyncData is set.